# Why are peripherals called upstream-facing ports?

Tags: usb, communication

I was surprised when I noted this naming in [USB-C Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C):

> Devices may be hosts (with a downstream-facing port, DFP) or
> peripherals (with an upstream-facing port, UFP).

The oil and gas industry uses upstream/downstream consist with river flow (upstream is toward where water originates, towards where oil originates.) It therefore came as a surprise to me that `USB host` (from where data and energy flow) is referred to as `downstream`. I searched the web and only found that meaning without explanation of the logic and how it originated.

Added:

The answer clearly show I missed `facing` part. It is still unclear why it was not called simply `Downstream` port, but called more lengthy `Upstream facing`.

Comment: The proposed "simpler" terminology wouldn't work when hubs get involved.  You would have an upstream end port and downstream end port, fine, but the upstream-facing port on the hub would be called downstream, the downstream-facing port on the hub would be called upstream, and the hub's upstream port would be downstream of its downstream port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A host is downstream-*facing*. As in, pointing in the direction of downstream. An upstream device looks downstream, and a downstream device looks upstream.

Comment: A host can face in any direction up or down.  is defined by control initiation protocol. Host is always initiator which is defined by upward tree hierarchy

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75: "Upstream" seems to be defined as "toward the host/initiator"

Comment: oops I missed `facing` part. Now I realized it is still unclear why it was not called simply `Upstream` port, but called more lengthy `downstream facing`

Comment: @Martian2020 I'm afraid I can't answer that; you'd have to ask someone more familiar with the standards than me.

Comment: @Martian2020 because "upstream port" is ambiguous. It could just as easily mean the thing you suggest, or the exact opposite. "Downstream-facing port" is intended to be unambiguous.

Comment: **Facing refers to control** not the follow-on traffic of a channel. The controller being higher in the hierarchical sense.

Comment: @hobbs good point, from the perspective of the USB chip in the peripheral, both ports are upstream.

Answer (score 1):

In general topology, a host polls or provides control to all down-level comm. channel devices. This is done by polling or listening to a channel from downstream clients.  In a tree, a host (or server) is above all the clients its serves by polling or listening for a request for a channel.

**Thus, a Host controls all traffic on a downward facing  port (DFP) and clients respond on upward facing ports (UFP) to a host.**

The term facing and direction means the port which is **facing down  controls the connection for traffic in a channel** not the actual content which may be up or downstream after the connection is made.

### USB-C DFP & UFP are configured with resistors on CC wire.

USB-C departs from traditional USB ports with the ability to use the same cable for a peripheral to allow any peripheral to be a client or host or dual direction by the voltage of pullup or down resistors on the Channel Configuration CC wire.

[image]

USB-C has two CC wire channels

[image]

[Source: TI](https://training.ti.com/sites/default/files/docs/USB_3.1_Type-C_solutions_TIpart_0.pdf)

In  a network, an intermediate node can be both a host and client.

Also,  thru-cables or cross-over cables had to be used depending on the upstream or downstream endport.

With USB-C this is no longer a requirement and the CC link voltage determines who can control the channel. High or pullup R meaning host for Down Facing Port.(DFP)